# How to draw a polygon overlay using MapKit and swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, point-in-polygon

I am trying to get the following code to draw a polygon on the map but for some reason it doesn't work. What did i go wrong here?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 49.140838, longitude: -123.127886)
        centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)
        addBoundry()
    }


    func addBoundry()
    {
        var points=[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(49.142677,  -123.135139),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(49.142730, -123.125794),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(49.140874, -123.125805),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(49.140885, -123.135214)]

        let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)

        mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
    }


    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
            regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }


}


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        if overlay is MKPolygon {
        let polygonView = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polygonView.strokeColor = UIColor.magentaColor()

        return polygonView
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear that you've implemented [`mapView(_:renderFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452203-mapview) (previously known as `rendererForOverlay`) as a global function.  The  method must be within the `ViewController` class definition or, even better, to keep our code nicely organized, within a `MKMapViewDelegate` extension:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, make sure that you've defined the view controller to be the `delegate` of the map view. It's probably easiest to do that in IB, but you can also do it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
mapView.delegate = self
```